# JQuery loop through multiple input checkboxes

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am tasked with having one checkbox within multiple divs.  When the checkbox is checked, I want to hide the div.  I want to use Jquery to implement this functionality.  I feel I am close, but missing something essential.

Here is my code and any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,

Roka

```
<div id='legGroup1' class="elementGroup">
    <input type="checkbox" class="delCheck" id="1" />Delete</label>
</div>

<div id='legGroup2' class="elementGroup">
    <input type="checkbox" class="delCheck" id="2" />Delete</label>
</div>

<button type='button' id='removeLeg'></button>

$("#removeLeg").click(function (e) {
    $('.delCheck').each(function () {
        if (this.id.prop('checked')) {
            $("#legGroup" + this.id).hide();
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply find the parent element:

```
$("#removeLeg").click(function() {
    $('.delCheck:checked').each(function() {
    //          ^^^^^^^^ -> look it filters only checked elements

        $(this).parent().hide();

    });
});
```

Or, more accurate, using closest method:

```
$(this).closest('.elementGroup').hide();
```

Answer (score 0):

Since your using an `each` function, base it off the value of the items in the array the function returns.

```
$("#removeLeg").click(function (e) {    
    $('.delCheck').each(function (key, value) {
       if ($(value).is(':checked')) {
           $(value).parent().hide();
       }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you're missing an open `label` tag in your HTML.

```
<label><input type="checkbox" class="delCheck" id="1" />Delete</label>
```

As for the click event, you can try this, to loop through each checked checkbox and hide their closest div parent.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#removeLeg').on('click', function(){
        $('.delCheck:checked').each(function(){
            $(this).parents('div').hide();
        });
    });
});
```

Here's a demo: https://jsfiddle.net/nx9e1yp5/1/